# Regex: do not match suffix containing substring

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

This is another regex question. I couldn't find any stackoverflow question that addressed my need.

I'm using java. I need a regex to match the following files:

- `my_file`
- `my_file.123`  (basically `my_file\.(\d+)` )

but I don't want to match:

- `my_file_name`
- `my_file_name.123`

I looked up negative lookaheads but that seems to only work if I know he absolute suffix. I think what I want is ad `my_file` that doesn't have `_` as the immediately following character.

How can I express the above regex? Thank you for reading.

Comment: `my_file(\.\d+)?`

Comment: "I think what I want is ..." - well, before you get programming help, you'll need to decide _exactly_ what it is that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to match `my_file` (and an *optional* literal `.` followed by digits). Like,

```
String[] arr = { "my_file", "my_file.123", "my_file_name", "my_file_name.123" };
String regex = "my_file(\\.\\d+)?";
for (String str : arr) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s%n", str, str.matches(regex));
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
my_file true
my_file.123 true
my_file_name false
my_file_name.123 false
```